Can the verb "be' be a dynamic verb?
I have read from many sources that 'be,' 'seem,' and 'become,' are always linking verbs. But I have seen a few sources mentioning 'be' as occasionally a dynamic verb as well.
If 'be' is always a linking verb, how do we take (explain) sentences like "He is being careful/silly" as linking and stative verbs are not used in continuous tense as per many sources?
Other forms of dynamic 'be' in imperative:
Be joyful. (= behave joyful)  Be quick. (= move quick)

"You're [just] being silly" is normal mainstream English (potentially distinct from "You're silly", which by default labels a permanent attribute rather than temporary behaviour), but "I am being happy" is non-standard Indian English in almost all conceivable contexts.

The semantic part is fine. But the question is: If it is ALWAYS linking ( as per sources like Grammarly), then how can they be in participle form (continuous)?

Not related to participles, but I certainly wouldn’t call it a linking verb in I think, therefore I am.

Yes - in certain contexts, 'be' can also convey a dynamic sense when used in the continuous or progressive form as you stated - "is being," "are being" etc. In these cases, it indicates an ongoing action or behaviour rather than a static state. When this is the case, it usually forms a dynamic verb phrase with another word rather than linking to an adjective or noun.
To use your example, "he is being silly", this uses a verb phrase. "Being silly" means behaving in a silly manner. It is different from saying "he is silly" because that ascribes an adjective to the person and suggests they are silly all of the time; that 'silly' is an attribute that person has.

What would you say about the non-continuous dynamic usage examples? If we say ' You be quick,' 'be' cannot be a dynamic verb as quick is an adjective and adjectives cannot modify a verb like adverbs.

@A_Mendes "quick" is a predicate adjective, so it's modifying the pronoun "you," not the verb "be." In that sentence, "be" is in the imperative mood. So, "You are [adj]" is a statement, while "You be [adj]" is the corresponding command, but it's a linking verb + predicate adjective in both constructions. I do believe the linking verb is being used "dynamically" in the second version, though, even though it's not continuous, because it refers to an action and not a static/unchanging quality.

@QuackE.Duck It is given as a dynamic verb and hence I asked that. I don't know whether I can post that link here. It is from a good source known as grammarquizzes dot com. They have all modern grammar interpretations like non-finite clauses for phrases,  be and if as connective prepositions compared to subordinate conjunctions by earlier standards.

@A_Mendes the imperative be can be both stative and dynamic - eg. Be honest and tell me the truth (dynamic) vs. Be honest and charitable (stative)
